# Reading a signed bits in Lua

Tags: lua, numbers, byte, bit, 16-bit

I have a 16-bit in a string but this is the representation of a signed number. Is there a way/function that do the converson from signed bits to decimal ?

The function tonumber() assumes the bits are unsigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Lua 5.3/5.4

Use [`string.unpack`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.unpack) with a format string [`<i2`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.2) to read the binary string. (use `>i2` for big endian data)

```
--0x8000 ---> -32768
local v = string.unpack('<i2', '\x00\x80')
```

#### Lua 5.2/5.1

There is no `string.unpack`, so you have to read each byte of the string, then compute the value manually.

```
local l, h = string.byte('\x00\x80', 1, 2)
local v = h * 256 + l --big endian: v = l * 256 + h
if v > 32767 then v = v - 65536 end
```